# “Found in build” dropdown in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

Any option we can set such like the latest build numbers in the 'found in' field be at the top whenever user select the value from the list?

This is to make sure users don't have to drag the control to select the appropriate build no to reduce time spent.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, there no easy way to sort suggested global list values in any order which is used by **Found in build** field, by default they will be ascended alphabetically.

Comment: Thanks and thats my opinion too.  Let me wait and hear if someone has any other way around for this